# Installing Windows 10 via USB 3.0 on Mac - is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, mac, installation, usb-3

I want to install Windows 10 on a Mac Mini (Late 2012) via USB stick (as the only OS - no Mac OS, no Bootcamp).

So, I keep reading that using USB 3.0 for installing Windows frequently causes the installation to fail. Is that still the case with 1703?

The Mac has 4 USB 3.0 ports and no USB 2.0 ports at all (and, by the way, no DVD drive).

Comment: Anniversary update (version 1607+) cannot be installed using USB 3.0 stick. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 10 install from USB 3.0 will not fail, assuming you got the right drivers - I installed 120+ times from USB 3.0 sticks and external USB using 3.0

However - since you are going to be running the install on HW that is not Windows Logo certified, the outcome is not 100%. I have never done install on Mac Mini without Bootcamp so I can't tell.

Bootcamp + Windows 1o via USB 3.0 works just fine...

Comment: Just in case, is there any way to include a driver package that can be loaded prior to installation? Back then there was a way to load SATA drivers via floppy disk during a Win XP installation, if I remember correctly. ;)

Comment: ...worked like a charm without additional USB drivers. The only thing you have to keep in mind is to use a FAT32 stick. exFat produced errors during installation (asked for some ominous drivers) and NTFS was not bootable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! but be careful with the partitions you choose to install Windows don't accidentally wipe the macOS partition

Comment: Indeed. I wiped it deliberately.